# Search multiple strings by index in a list

Tags: python, list

I have stored in a list an output of a command, this output belongs to a cisco Switch. I would like to print the errors that have occurred in the configuration, this is shown in the output when this text appears: "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", above this text is this symbol: '^' and finally above this symbol the erroneous command.

For this, I have stored each command line in a list, in this list are stored several "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", what can I do to make it show several of these erroneous commands? I have a code that looks for these errors, but in this case I get 2 times the same erroneous code stored in the list.

this is the list:

```
['configure terminal', 'Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.', 'PERIKO11(config)#hostname PERIKO11', 'PERIKO11(config)#', 'PERIKO11(config)#int eth0/0', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi', '                     ^', "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", '', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#exit', 'PERIKO11(config)#', 'PERIKO11(config)#line vty 5 10', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#password 1234', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#loginasdasdfasdf', '                           ^', "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", '', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#loggin sync', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#exit', 'PERIKO11(config)#end', 'PERIKO11#']
```

I have the following code:

```
output = net_connect.send_config_from_file(cfg_file)

out = []
buff = []
for ca in output:
    if ca == '\n':
        out.append(''.join(buff))
        buff = []
    else:
        buff.append(ca)
else:
    if buff:
        out.append(''.join(buff))
print(out)

search="% Invalid input detected at '^' marker."
                
                
for x in range(0,len(out)):
                    
    if out[x] == search:
        index3=out.index(search)
        index2=index3-1
        index1=index2-1

        print(out[index1])
        print(out[index2])
        print(out[index3])
```

this is the output of my code:

```
PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi
                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.


PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi
                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

As you can see, the same erroneous command is repeated since it only appears once in the list. The 2nd wrong code that is in the list should be printed but it does not appear, the 1st wrong code appears instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a fixed-size [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to do it:

```
from collections import deque

output = ['configure terminal', 'Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.', 'PERIKO11(config)#hostname PERIKO11', 'PERIKO11(config)#', 'PERIKO11(config)#int eth0/0', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi', '                     ^', "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", '', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#', 'PERIKO11(config-if)#exit', 'PERIKO11(config)#', 'PERIKO11(config)#line vty 5 10', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#password 1234', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#loginasdasdfasdf', '                           ^', "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.", '', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#\x07', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#loggin sync', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#', 'PERIKO11(config-line)#exit', 'PERIKO11(config)#end', 'PERIKO11#']

buffer = deque('', 3)

search = "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker."

for line in output:
    buffer.append(line)
    if line == search:
        print('\n'.join(buffer))
        print('----')
```

Output:

```
PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi
                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
----
PERIKO11(config-line)#loginasdasdfasdf
                           ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
----
```